# convert PDF to image/flash/something in PHP

Tags: php, flash, pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

I need a solution to convert dynamically created multi-page PDF files to another format, like Jpegs or an swf file etc. I know about `Ghostscript` and `ImageMagick`, but neither are of any use to me as our service provider cannot (will not) grant enough permissions to allow them run with PHP exec, system, et al commands (just gives the old *"unable to fork"*). On my exhaustive searches I have [come across this](http://brettvanderhaar.com/php-windows-server-2008iis7-unable-to-fork-error-with-ghostscript/) but I have no idea how to implement it, how to generate this asmx file etc.

The PDF file sits on the server after creation so I just need to be able to call something then through another function to convert them.

Even if someone knows of a hosted service that I can call from PHP or some other way to make the conversion of the PDF file this would be useful as at the moment I have run out of ideas.